# tomcat do not unpack war file

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, war

i stopped tomcat 
paste myapp.war into webapps folder.
start tomcat
call in browser

http://localhost:8080/myapp/index.jsf

see 404

also tomcat does not generate log files under logs directory.
I am using eclipse to start and stop tomcat, and my tomcat 7 is an unzipped version.
to be sure that my war file runs on server, i remove same project from tomcat in eclipse servers view.

repeating question, but i think my situation is a little different, tomcat does not generate logs.

a note: i generate war file by right click in eclipse-> export war file.

thanks for any idea.

Comment: invalid url replace localhost with ipadd

Comment: restart tomcat from eclipse it may solve ur problem

Answer (score 0):

If you are launching tomcat from within Eclipse (using the webtools tomcat server adapter) you will have to make sure you have changed the settings to use the installation directory to launch instead of the default which uses a separate location for loading and deploying webapps. So if you add a war directly into the webapps folder, the server launched from Eclipse server adapter wont have that directly setup in the server.xml configuration.

So you should use the startup.bat/startup.sh in the tomcat/bin folder.  If you do, you need to make sure that you don't just copy the .war file into the webapps, but rather unzip the war file into a directory folder called "myapp"